# How to make UWP App available to only selected users

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I have UWP app in the store, but now I want to make new update available to only selected customers with registered email-id. I found that this can be possible by generating package flights and creating user group, but by that old version will be still available for download for general public or those who have app link.
Is it possible to remove current app package so that if even user has an app link, he can't download app any further but only users mentioned in package flight group can download my app. 
Thanks.

I also tried to make product unavailable, and in package update there's no option to distribute package to only selected user.
Please check below screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to remove current app package so that if even user has an app link, he can't download app any further but only users mentioned in package flight group can download my app.

First you may need to make your old app unavailable by clicking the "Make product unavailable" as following:
[image]
After that you can create a new submission and let your UWP App only available to  selected users by changing the distribution options in the "Distribution and visibility" as @Daniel Krzyczkowski said.
[image]

Besides, if you only want to let your UWP app available for selected users for testing purpose, you can creat a Beta version of your app, for more information, please check:
[Beta testing and targeted distribution.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/beta-testing-and-targeted-distribution)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but It's now showing me 3rd option for specifying user after making product unavailable and than updating the current version.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can change distribution options in the "Distribution and visibility" section when updating the package.

You can generate promotional codes to distribute to specific people on Windows 10.
This will ensure that your app is visible only to selected people.
Please see this post:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/set-app-pricing-and-availability#distribution-and-visibility

Comment: It's now showing promotional code option during update, please check my edited post.